# Read a file or read a standard user input

Tags: bash

I was having a problem when writing a bash script. I was required to write a script that can be called in 2 ways, read a file or read a standard input. However, when I used a while-read, I can no longer make it read standard input. Here is my code:

```
#!/bin/bash
FILE=$1
while read LINE; 
do
    echo "$LINE" | tr " " "\n" | tr "\t" "\n"
done < $FILE
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem comes from the fact that you always give $FILE as input to your read.
You could try redirecting the file to channel 0 when you have an argument and leave it to stdin otherwise.

```
#!/bin/bash
FILE=$1
if [ ! -z "$FILE" ]
then
  exec 0< "$FILE"
fi
while read LINE
do
    echo "$LINE" | tr " " "\n" | tr "\t" "\n"
done
```

`exec 0< "$FILE"` tells the shell to use $FILE as input for channel 0. Reminder: by default `read` listens to channel 0.

`0<` is the key here, where `0` indicates channel 0 and `<` indicates this is an input. When there is no argument, `exec 0< "$FILE"` will *not* be called, in this case channel 0 will use stdin.

Comment: By the way, I tend to say “channel 0” but for Bash the exact term is “file descriptor 0”. You can check the current fd0 with: `lsof -a -p $$ -d0`

Comment: Thanks buddy, I just did some further study about this language, still a noob currently :P.

Answer (score 2):

UNIX tools by convention use the special filename `-` to indicate that input comes from stdin. You can adapt that:

```
file="${1}"
if [ "${file}" = "-" ] ; then
    file=/dev/stdin # special device for stdin
fi

while read -r line ; do
    do something
done < "${file}"
```

You can now call the tool like this

```
tool -             # reads from terminal
cmd | tool -       # used in a pipe
tool /path/to/file # reads from file
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I will try it and do some further study on bash. I am still a starter for this language :)

Comment: Agreed `-` is usually treated as stdin. But `/dev/stdin` should be avoided as there are many cases where it doesn’t work as intended. And by forcing the use of `-` the script can not read from a pipe.

Comment: In some cases the assignment `file=$(</dev/stdin)` tends to behave better.

Comment: @vdavid Of course you can use it in in a pipe: `cmd | tool -`. Besides that, why should I avoid `/dev/stdin` ? Please elaborate on those *many* cases

Comment: `bash` guarantees that `/dev/stdin`, when used for redirection, refers to standard input, whether or not the file system actually has such an entry. `file=$(</dev/stdin)` would read the entire file at once, something you probably don't want to do.